# Same AngularJS custom directive on same page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom search directive and need to use multiple instances of it on the same page.  The page makes use of bootstrap tabs and there will be an instance of this search component in each tab.

The issue is that the search directive in the second tab is overriding the callback of the search directive in the first tab.  Here is a snippet of my search directive:

```
class SearchDirective {

constructor($timeout) {
    this.require = '^ngModel';
    this.restrict= "AE";
    this.$timeout = $timeout;
    this.scope = {
        ngModel: '=',
        searchTime: '=',
        searchCallback: '&'
    };
}


compile(tElem, tAttrs) {
    return this.link.bind(this);
}


link(scope, element, attrs) {
    this.scope = scope;
    var timer = null;

    scope.$watch('ngModel', (value, preValue) => {
        if (value === preValue) return;

        if (timer) {
            this.$timeout.cancel(timer);
        }
        timer = this.$timeout(() => {
            timer = null;
            if (value.length === 0) {
                this.scope.searchCallback();
            }
        }, this.scope.searchTime)
    });  
  }
}
```

And here is a snippet of the HTML for the search component on the first tab:

```
 <input search search-callback="searchWindowsController.searchPcs()" search-time="600" data-ng-model="searchWindowsController.searchQuery" type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search Windows...">
```

And this is what i have in the second tab:

```
<input search search-callback="searchMacController.searchPcs()" search-time="600" data-ng-model="searchMacController.searchQuery" type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search Macs...">
```

For some reason when you search using the Windows search, it is calling the Mac callback.  Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?  I am new to custom directives.

Comment: They dont seem to have an isolated scope. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive this might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error due to `this` within the `$timeout` function.

See live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/329pdvry/).

```js
'use strict'
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.callback1 = function(){
     console.log('callback1');
    };
     $scope.callback2 = function(){
     console.log('callback2');
    };
  })
.directive('search',function($timeout){
 return new SearchDirective($timeout);
});
class SearchDirective {

  constructor(timeout) {
    this.require = '^ngModel';
    this.restrict = "AE";
    this.$timeout = timeout;
    this.scope = {
      ngModel: '=',
      searchTime: '=',
      searchCallback: '&'
    };
  }


  compile(tElem, tAttrs) {
    return this.link.bind(this);
  }


  link(scope, element, attrs) {
    this.scope = scope;
    var timer = null;
    scope.$watch('ngModel', (value, preValue) => {
      if (value === preValue) return;

      if (timer) {
        this.$timeout.cancel(timer);
      }
      timer = this.$timeout(() => {
        timer = null;
        if (value.length === 0) {
          scope.searchCallback();
        }
      }, scope.searchTime)
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <input search search-callback="callback1()" search-time="600" data-ng-model="searchQuery1" type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search Mac...">
      <input search search-callback="callback2()" search-time="600" data-ng-model="searchQuery2" type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search Windows...">
  </div>
</div>
```